# cygwin perl error cannot load expat.dll

Tags: perl, windows-7, cygwin, expat-parser

```
c:\>perl -de 1

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.32
Editor support available.

Enter h or `h h' for help, or `man perldebug' for more help.

main::(-e:1):   1
  DB<1> require XML::Parser::Expat
Can't load '/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10/i686-cygwin/auto/XML/Parser/Expat/Expat.dll' for module XML::Parser::Expat: No such file or directory at /usr/lib
/perl5/5.10/i686-cygwin/DynaLoader.pm line 200.
 at (eval 5)[/usr/lib/perl5/5.10/perl5db.pl:638] line 2
Compilation failed in require at (eval 5)[/usr/lib/perl5/5.10/perl5db.pl:638] line 2.

  DB<2> q

c:\>
```

Anyone encountered this before? How to fix it? My cygwin is located in `C:\cygwin`

there is no directory `C:\cygwin\usr\lib` but there is `C:\cygwin\lib`. when I open up `bash` and try to `cd /usr/lib` it succeeds(surprisingly) and after a `ls` it seems the contents are the same as of the directory `C:\cygwin\lib`.

That said, the directory `C:\cygwin\lib\perl5\vendor_perl\5.10\i686-cygwin\auto\XML\Parser\Expat` contains a file named `Expat.dll`.

It seems that cygwin says it can't find this file but then how can it find `/usr/lib/perl5/5.10/i686-cygwin/DynaLoader.pm`?

I tried doing `chmod +x` but that doesn't fix it.

Any Help?

doing `perl -MXML::Parser::Expat -e1` on the command line returns:

```
c:\dev\trunk\src>perl -MXML::Parser::Expat -e1
Can't load '/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10/i686-cygwin/auto/XML/Parser/Expat/Expat.dll' for module XML::Parser::Expat: No such file or directory at /usr/lib
/perl5/5.10/i686-cygwin/DynaLoader.pm line 200.
 at -e line 0
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

***EDIT***:
Also, when I do the same in cygwin bash environment(not in cmd directly), there is no error!

Comment: Try `perl -MXML::Parser::Expat -e1` in a Cygwin shell. Also, when you say just `perl` on the `cmd.exe` command-line, which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going into cygwin bash shell first and then doing whatever I want does not give this error.
So I'd suggest move all your perl commands of your bat script to a shell script and invoke that with `bash`.